# A simple filtering problem

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\{\mathscr{F}_t\},P)$ be a probability space. Suppose $X$ is a random variable which only takes two values $x_1$ and $x_2$, and $X\in\mathscr{F}_0$. Let $\{W_t\}$ be standard $\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$ Brownian motion. Assume $dY_t=u_t^{\frac{1}{2}}X\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}W_t$, where $u$ is $\mathscr{F}_t^Y\equiv\sigma\{Y_s:s\leq t\}$ adapted.

Define $\phi_t=E(1_{\{x_1\}}(X)|\mathscr{F}_t^Y)$. Using Girsanov theorem and Ito's rule, I got $$\mathrm{d}\phi_t=\phi_t(1-\phi_t)(x_1-x_2)u_t^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\mathrm{d}Y_t-u_t^{\frac{1}{2}}(\phi_t x_1+(1-\phi_t)x_2)\mathrm{d}t\Big).$$ But the answer in the solution is given by  $$\mathrm{d}\phi_t=\phi_t(1-\phi_t)(x_1-x_2)u_t^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}W_t.$$

Which is correct? Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i got into a typesetting mess i couldn't get out of:  my suggestion is do the case $u_t=$ constant explicitly.  I think they are the same, that your expression  in  big parens is dW under the full measure